# Show that $\operatorname{Span}(C) = V_1 \cap V_2$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let $\mathbb{R}[x]$ be the set of polynomials, and let
>
> $$V_1 = \{a_1x + a_2x^3 + a_3x^5 \mid a_1, a_2, a_3 \in \mathbb{R}\}$$
>
> $$V_2 = \{b_1x^2 + b_2x^3 + b_3x^4 \mid b_1, b_2, b_3 \in \mathbb{R}\}$$
>
> be subsets of $\mathbb{R}[x]$. View $\mathbb{R}[x]$ as a vector space.
>
> You may assume that $V_2$ and $V_1 \cap V_2$ are linear subspaces of  $\mathbb{R}[x].$
>
> Give a basis C for $V_1 \cap V_2$ and show that $\operatorname{Span}(C) = V_1 \cap V_2$.

Just by looking at the sets, I have found that $C = \{x^3\}$.

I know that $\operatorname{Span}(C)$ is the set of all linear combinations of the elements in $C$ (which is just $x^3$) - but I'm not sure how to actually show that $\operatorname{Span}(C) = V_1 \cap V_2$.

Answer (score 1):

You have $\operatorname{Span}(C)=\{ax^3 \mid a\in\mathbb{R}\}$.

$v\in V_1\cap V_2 \implies v \in V_1 \text{ and } v \in V_2$. This means $v=a_1 x+a_2 x^3+a_3 x^5$ since $v$ is in $V_1$, and $v=b_1 x^2+b_2 x^3+b_3 x^4$ since $v$ is in $V_2$. The only way that $v$ can be in both of these sets is if $v$ is cubic. We must have that $v=cx^3$ with $c \in \mathbb{R}$.